# Using @Produces with @Qualifier

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

Is there any way to force the use of producer method if using `@Qualifier`? I have a `@Produces` factory method but the constructor is still being called, which is an issue because I need the `InjectionPoint` to read parameters. Using the code below `RRRRRRRR` is always printed out.

```
@ProductTypeA
public class ProductA implements Product
{
    public String test="testA";

    private ProductA()
    {
        System.out.println("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
        this.test = "testB";
    }
    private ProductA(InjectionPoint injectionpoint)
    {
        System.out.println("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
        this.test="testC";
    }
    @Produces
    public ProductA getProductA(InjectionPoint injectionpoint)
    {
        this.test="testD";
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("injectionpoint.getAnnotated() = "+injectionpoint.getAnnotated());
        return new ProductA(injectionpoint);
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedList<Feature> getFeatures()
    {
        LinkedList<Feature> rtn = new LinkedList<Feature>();
        rtn.add( new Feature("AAA","111") );
        return rtn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ProductA []";
    }

}
```

Qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface ProductTypeA
{
    @Nonbinding
    String testfield() default "23";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qualifier should be in the producer method:

```
@Produces
@ProductTypeA
public ProductA getProductA(InjectionPoint injectionpoint)
{
    this.test="testD";
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("injectionpoint.getAnnotated() = "+injectionpoint.getAnnotated());
    return new ProductA(injectionpoint);
}
```

Comment: thanks, moving it from the class to the @Produces worked perfectly. All of the tutorials seems to skip over some key points like this that are needed to make CDI work

Comment: Do you have an example of such a tutorial?